# Having problems with generating new values with Objects

Tags: java, user-interface

On my **GraphicalInterface.java** at Issue 3, I am having troubles in generating new list of numbers since is using the same object. How would I achieve in generating new numbers?

```
private void optionMethod() {
    button = new JButton("Generate Frequency!");
    button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //Issue #2: What if exceeds the range from 10?                  
                int minRangeValue = Integer.parseInt(minRange.getText());
                int maxRangeValue = Integer.parseInt(maxRange.getText());
                int lengthValue = Integer.parseInt(value.getText());

                //Issue #3: Numbers are being generated only one time.
                gen.generateNumber(lengthValue, minRangeValue, maxRangeValue);
                for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                    frequencyStatsLabel[i].setText(gen.frequencyNumber(i+1) + "%"); 
                }       
                System.out.println("[Console]: Min Range: " + minRange.getText());
                System.out.println("[Console]: Max Range: " + maxRange.getText());
                System.out.println("[Console]: Length: " + value.getText());
                System.out.println("[Console]: All numbers have been generated.");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[Click here](https://gist.github.com/hahajoker181/b14898bfe89c52970fb08efc7ef6e802) to view the source code.

Comment: Why generate numbers and stored it inside a static variable? You need to rethink your logic. The method generateNumber should return a List of numbers then you can assign to any variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Minh Kieu, I was able to find the issue in my program. So apparently I had a `static` ArrayList which is why the instance wouldn't change. I have remove the static from the ArrayList, now my ActionList would generate new number list, to update the data.